# Get Value of Post before

Tags: posts, loop

I have a normal loop in wordpress and in every post i need to check the value of the post before to compare it with the current post.

-- POST 1 --
** DO NOTHING **

-- POST 2 --
** GET VALUE FROM POST 1 **

-- POST 3 --
** GET VALUE FROM POST 2 **

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();

                  $description = get_post_meta( get_the_ID( ), 'metabox_description', true );       
                  echo $description;

                  // Add: echo $description_from_post_before;

        } // end while
    } // end if
?>
```

Comment: put some code to review

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$previous_post=null;
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
             global $post;
            if($previous_post!=null)
            {
              /// Do what ever you want to do with previous post $previous_post.
            }


                  $description = get_post_meta( get_the_ID( ), 'metabox_description', true );       
                  echo $description;

                  // Add: echo $description_from_post_before;
            $previous_post = $post;
        } // end while
    } // end if
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `get_previous_post()` to get the previous post object.

```
$prev = get_previous_post();
if ( !empty( $prev ) ) {
   // Do some comparing
}
```

Hope this helps